# PostgreSQL 11 spring JPA query error with java.sql.Date object and TO_DATE fucntion with format YYYY-DD-MM

Tags: java, postgresql, date, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-11

I am passing `java.sql.Date` object to CrudRepository native query. This date object is passed to a date function with a format ('YYYY-DD-MM'). This query is working with PostgreSQL 9.4, but it gives error when the database is PostgreSQL 11. I tried JDBC driver v42.2.11 and 9.1-901-1. Both are giving same result.

The error message is:

```
ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2020-05-27 +00:00"
```

Code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TO_DATE(?1, 'YYYY-DD-MM')", nativeQuery = true)
public String sampleQuery(java.sql.Date date);
```

When I gave the date format as `"SELECT TO_DATE(?1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"`, that time it worked in PostgreSQL 11.

Any idea what is happening here.

Comment: Calling `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date` makes no sense whatsoever. So if you pass a `java.sql.Date`  instance to the query, then your query makes no sense. Did you mean to use `to_char()` in order to format the data?

Comment: By the way, the terrible `java.sql.Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, specially `LocalDate`. Both JPA 2.2 and recent Hibernate have been updated to support *java.time* types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 27 is not a valid month it should not work:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                 version                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_date('2020-05-27 +00:00','YYYY-DD-MM');
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2020-05-27 +00:00"
postgres=#
```

And if it works in 9.4 it gives an unexpected result:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                    version                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.26 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_date('2020-05-27 +00:00','YYYY-DD-MM');
  to_date   
------------
 2022-03-09
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Comment: Impressive catch!